# tag based table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to create several table of contents with redundant entries based on special tags next to a full table of contents?

Let's assume a book full of short stories for kids. There are 5 stories:

- "Little Peter, the little cowboy"
- "Pretty Maria plays with her doll"
- "The fast Porsche Driver is awesome"
- "The thrilling adventures of Jimmy"
- "Sarah has a Tea party"

Now I want, next to the complete table of contents, one which simply groups stories based on tags I define like this:

```
\section{Little Peter, the little cowboy}
\myTags{western, boys, adventure}
```

and then a toc: \tableofcontents{western} which lists all western stories.

I guess there is nothing, which already exists, but I even don't know where to start. Should I just try to start with own tocs or better try to reformat an index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package [tableof](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tableof) does that.

If the document class (for example  `article`)  allows only a single use of `\tableofcontents` command, then the package provides `\tableof`, `\tablenotof` and the more general `\tableoftaggedcontents`, but:

1. you need to set up the heading, e.g. with `\section*{A table of tagged contents}`,

   ```
   \section*{Western stuff}
   \tableof{western}
   ```
2. your document should have a global `\tableofcontents`, else and if and only if it doesn't, a `\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}` in the preamble is asked for.

If the document class allows multiple use of `\tableofcontents` you may use rather `\nexttocwithtags{foo...}{bar...}\tableofcontents` where `foo, ...` is required and `bar, ...` excluded.

```
\nexttocwithtags{western}{}
\tableofcontents
```

These are excerpts from the documentation which explains how you set-up the tags:

```
\toftagthis{western, famous people, twentieth century}
\section{John Ford}

\toftagthis{kitchen, health}
\section{Chocolate cake}
```

Comment: A very smooth solution. And it works well with hyperref as well. Thank you.